# Is this a correct representation of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, measure-theory, statistics

I have the set ($a$,$b$]. I am considering the sigma field generated by all open, bounded intervals of $\mathbb R$. Can I write $$(a,b]= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-\tfrac{1}{n},b]$$

Comment: $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n},b]=[a,b]$.

Comment: @Will Yes thank you. How would I modify that for the open interval for a ? By changing the $-$ to a $+$?

Comment: Don't you want to take a limit in the $b$ end instead?
$$(a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a, b+\frac 1 n)$$

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry that's what I meant. That makes sense.

Comment: @Will Can't I just write that $(a,b] = (a,\infty)$ \ $(b, \infty)$. Then $(a,\infty) = \bigcup_{i=k_a}^{\infty} (a,i) $ and do the same for $(b,\infty)$?